Is there any way to test API's for multiple smart meters, providing there ids?
I am currently testing APIs for smart meters, where I test one device at a time by hitting the endpoints and receiving responses. However, I am now preparing to test multiple devices simultaneously on postman by providing device id. How can I accomplish this?
I am not sure as I am new to this.

What have you tried so far?  What research have you done?  Have you tried the Postman Learning Centre docs which should show you how to use the collection runner and data files?
